# Mobile Audio HTML5 limit resources

Tags: html, audio

I am developing an HTML5 Audio Web & Mobile App.

I am preloading audio by starting the preload after clicking on a "start" button, in order to elude the autopreload block in mobile device.

But the preaload always stops at a certain point.

I wonder if there is a weight limit in HTML5 audio contents on Mobile Browsers.

I am Using Safari Mobile on Iphone and Ipad (also emulators on  Mac have the same behaviour).

Debugging with Developer Tools, i don'r receive any alert / error.

When i try load a single mp3 file ointing the file url ( www.mysite.com/audio.mp3 ) i receive an alert on the browser console: Nework Error. Isn't this strange?

Comment: Can you show some example code with what you are doing?  Browsers always have the option of doing what they think will make for a faster user experience.

Comment: i am isolating the problem, since the whole web app is too big. I will update the post asap